# Oracle SQL - GROUP BY not working

Tags: sql, oracle

When I am run the below query, I get the following result.

I don't understand why I am not getting the expected result from the GROUP BY.

How can I fix this so I get the expected result?

```
SELECT
  status AS "ROW LABELS",
  (case when order = 'INTERNET' THEN COUNT(*) end) AS "INTERNET"
FROM
    order
    ,status
WHERE  order       =   status
GROUP BY status, order_source
order by 1;
```

Data is here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzWMxMDCgXFaSk5TTWV2SEEzTFU/edit?usp=sharing
I couldn't format the data here well.

Following Dnoeth's answer, I am getting the below result:
[image]
See, I need the row labels to be grouped up, but they're not being grouped. Putting count outside the case helped a little. 
I have edited the query to get the idea across, the query is more complicated than what I am presenting here

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: What is the expected result? Your query works so we need to know what you are after to be able to help.

Comment: That can't be your real query, because `WHERE order = status` will generate an error as `order` is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some typo (order instead of order_source) you need to move the CASE inside the COUNT:

```
SELECT
  status AS "ROW LABELS",
  COUNT(case when order_source = 'INTERNET' THEN 1 end) AS "INTERNET"
FROM
    order
    ,status
WHERE  order       =   status
GROUP BY status
order by 1;
```

Comment: Hey thx, I've updated. I didn't notice the format until after posting. Yea just typo here, I'm not getting any errors. I've uploaded an image showing what I mean.